# Estimating a nonlinear function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, inequality

Let $F$ be a function in $C(\mathbb{C},\mathbb{C})$ with $F(x)=|x|^\mu x$, where $\mu>0$. I can show that that there exists a constant $C$ such that
$$
|F(x)-F(y)|\le C(|x|^\mu+|y|^\mu)|x-y|
$$
for all $x,y\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\mu>0$. However, I am wondering if it's also possible to prove something similar for a function $G_j\in C(\mathbb{C}^n, \mathbb{C})$ such that
$$
G_j(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^2\right)^\mu x_j.
$$
I would expect to get a similar result, i.e.
$$
|G_j(x_1,\dots,x_n)-G_j(y_1,\ldots,y_n)|\le C\left(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^{2\mu}+\sum_{k=1}^n |y_k|^{2\mu}\right)|x_j-y_j|
$$
for all $\mu>0$, $x_1,\ldots,x_n, y_1,\ldots,y_n \in \mathbb{C}$, and for all $j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to show this. What can we say about $|G_j(x_1,\dots,x_n)-G_j(y_1,\ldots,y_n)|$?